# Summary in group header in crystal report 2010

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report (In Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2010) and I need a few `Count` summaries in the group header. Also, the summaries have some conditions.

Example: I have a column named "Student_Id", I need a `Count` in the group header for every class from that group. I also have some date in group='class'. But, this summary was shown before every data.

I tried many different ways so far, but I realized that the group header is printed before the section details and that's why they didn't work. I want to show these summaries before starting every page.

The report looks like as the follows:

```
    class   Count_Student
    5        14
    6        20


    Class     5

    StudentID   Stu Name    Father-s name   

    1                       
    2                       
    3                       
    4                       
    5   

...


    Class   6

    StudentID   Stu Name    Father-s name


...
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on that field which you want to get sum. `Insert -> Summary` . Then copy that summary field in to the group header.Thus your problem is solved.